# How to do conditional markup in shared view (_Layout.cshtml)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, master-pages

I have a pure CSS dropdown menu that I've put in a shared view, so that no matter where user navigates to the menu is available. I want to determine the visibility of menu items according to user role. Something like this (Just a fragment of razor):

```
<ul>
@if(userRole==1||userRole==2)
   <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
```

But I have no idea how to do it as :

<s>1. I have no access to ViewBag, otherwise I could just set the user role in ViewBag and read it</s>

2. I cannot strongly type the shared view to some model.

What are your suggestions?

EDIT: Actually you can set and access ViewBag. that solves the problem.

Comment: Why do you have _"no access to ViewBag"_?

Comment: Because I set ViewBag in an action method. As I can't render the shared view alone, I thought I can't get access to it.

Comment: Yeah, @StephenMuecke, it really works. I should've checked before posting the question. Thank you for that.

Comment: No reason you cant set `ViewBag.User=SomeValue in your action methods. You could even create an action filter that add this value to all views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `User` object:

```
<ul>
   @if(User.IsInRole("firstRole") || User.IsInRole("secondRole"))
   {
       <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
    }
...
</ul>
```

Of course, this solution requires that you use a `RoleProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

For simple solution and for using multiple time you can try this

```
1) Create One BaseViewModel Class
2) put userRole property in that class (you can set this property where you want,you can set value in session and get..etc..etc..)
3) inherit BaseViewModel in required Model(may be one or more)
4) Use BaseViewModel in shared views
```